# Lockscreen widget default to expanded on Android 4.3 or upcoming 4.4

Tags: lock-screens, email, 4.3-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat, app-widgets

Does anyone know if there is a configuration to allow the lockscreen widget to default to expanded view on Android 4.3 or higher?  I have a Note 3 and have not yet received the 4.4 update.

I prefer NOT to use a 3rd party app.  My preference is to use the stock email widget, but have it in expanded mode by default.

Comment: So the 4.2 method doesn't work for you?

Comment: in 4.4 Google has changed the widget to be condensed by default. Even dashclock is condensed by default and there is no current workaroud for it (not sure any of any Xposed module for availabe for that).

Comment: @MatthewRead  Thanks for your comment.  No, I get so many emails and am used to glancing at the screen (of my iPhone) while on my computer or driving and seeing several of the latest emails without having to touch the device.  I just got a Note 3 and love the device, but this is a minor loss in functionality for me.

Comment: @k1chy Thanks, that is what I was afraid of.  I guess I will just live with it.  Thanks for your input